# LINQ select null values from List

Tags: linq, select, null, where-clause

I have a `List<string>` and it may contain null values in random indexes. I want to check which elements `null` and select that elements for throwing message.

What i am using;

```
List<string> getNames = EbaUsers.GetNamesFromIds(activeDirectoryInfo[7],
 activeDirectoryInfo[8], activeDirectoryInfo[9], activeDirectoryInfo[10]);

if(getNames[7].Equals(null))
{
     MessageBox.Show("getNames[7] is null");
}
if(getNames [8].Equals(null))
{
     MessageBox.Show("getNames[8] is null");
}
if(getNames[9].Equals(null))
{
     MessageBox.Show("getNames[9] is null");
}
if(getNames[10].Equals(null))
{
     MessageBox.Show("getNames[10] is null");
}
```

I know this is very easy to do with LINQ but i haven't found anywhere.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to first project the strings to index/value pairs, then pick the elements with null values, and project to just the indexes:

```
var nullIndexes = names.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                       .Where(pair => pair.value == null)
                       .Select(pair => pair.index)
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the index by [Enumerable.Select() with index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) and check if the info is null:

```
var nullInfoIndexes = activeDirectoryInfo.Select((info, index) => new {info, index})
                                         .Where(x => x.info == null)
                                         .Select(x => x.index);
foreach (var index in nullInfoIndexes)
    MessageBox.Show("activeDirectoryInfo[" + index + "] is null");
```